# Concatenation inside CONTAINS function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Here is a simplified snippet of what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT StreetNumber + StreetName AS 'Address'
FROM TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS('Address', 'Street Name')
```

I realize that I cannot use an alias here since the WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT clause.

The following two alternatives also do not work:

1)

```
SELECT Street_Number + StreetName AS 'Address'
FROM TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(CONCAT(StreetNumber, '', StreetName), 'Street Name')
```

2)

```
SELECT Street_Number + StreetName AS 'Address'
FROM TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(StreetNumber + ' ' + StreetName), 'Street Name')
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you aware of what `CONTAINS` is? I.e. That it is a full text index function and not  equivalent to  `string.Contains`?

Comment: If the address is "123 Main Street" it should appear with any of the following:

"Main 123 Street"
"Street Main"
"Street 123"

etc.

Comment: Ah OK sounds like you are aware then. Would have been easier if you were hoping for string.contains semantics!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually handle this with a subquery.  I do not like to copy and paste code like a concat or row_number assignment from the select list to a clause so I would handle like this:

```
Select Address From 
(
    SELECT StreetNumber + StreetName AS 'Address'
    FROM TABLE
) A
WHERE CONTAINS(Address, 'Street Name') 
-- Or maybe you really want  WHERE Address Like '%Street Name%'
```

I also think it is easier to read / maintain this code.  As commented contains works with full text indexes so you really might be looking for Charindex or Like instead.

Comment: That will full text search for a string literal "Street Name" not the value of that column.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's a good point, but I do have other logic that would handle the formatting of the input parameter that would be in place of the string literal "Street Name" - I should have clarified that earlier.

JoeC In order to create a full-text index on this concatenated "Address" column, I believe I need to create a view and then create the full-text index on the column in the view and then adjust the data source of the inner query.